# GenyMotion virtual devices do not have internet

Tags: android-emulator, virtualization, genymotion

I'm able to launch virtual devices, however none of them have any internet connection:
[image: No internet]

These are the VirtualBox network settings for adapter 1 and 2 for the virtual device:
[image: adapter 1]
[image: adapter 2]

These are all my network connection adapters in Windows:
[image: network adapters windows]

I have tried with multiple different devices and uninstalled and reinstalled Genymotion & VirtualBox. Hyper-V is also disabled on my machine (I'm running Windows 11 Pro).

I'd appreciate any help you can provide!